# Using of bulk upate via Query.executeUpdate() vs. object's set methods for multiple entities

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Sometime, in he case when we have a list of entity IDs, I have to update a set of fields of a collection of related of passed IDs entities and I am wandering in which cases is better to use the standard way via 1-st: loading of all entities and 2-nd: calling related set() methods :

```
List<Long> ids = ....;
String par = "example";
List<User> users = USER_DAO.getUsers(ids);
for(User user : users) {
   user.setField(par);
}
```

or the other way is via executing of a bulk update operations like :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE User user SET user.field =:1? WHERE user.id IN : 2?");
int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
```

Do you have some knowledge and/or investigations of that issue ? 
Or the cases, when first way is better than the second way or vs. ?

All recommendations are welcome, 
Thanks, 
SImeon

Answer (score 1):

The second way will perform better as there will be less sql's executed on the database.  In your first case two sql's will be executed for each user(one for the select and one for the update).  In your first case you will also take a performance hit while hibernate maps the sql to the object.